# Having a problem with pass by reference in two dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I have a variable called `names` which is a two dimensional array. 
I declared it like below so that there will be maximum of 5 names and each name will consist of 256 characters.

```
int main(){
    char names[5][256];
    strcpy(names[0],"John");
    strcpy(names[1],"Matt");
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(names)/256);        //this prints out 5 which is correct
    passit(names);             
}

void passit(char names[][256]){
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(names)/256);        //this prints out 8 which seems to be a size of pointer
}
```

How should I change this so that in `passit` function, number of elements will be printed correctly?

Comment: Where are you passing by reference?

Comment: your observation is right, you are actually passing a pointer (and the `/256` is just a typo, right?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is C-style. If you're really writing C++ then I suggest using `std::cout`, `std::vector` and `std::string`:

```
void passit(std::vector<std::string> const& names) {
    std::cout << names.size();
} 

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> names(5);
    names[0] = "John";
    names[1] = "Matt";

    std::cout << names.size();
    passit(names);             
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can perform an intermediate fix to your existing code.

As you've spotted, when you try to pass an array by value it actually decays to a pointer (`char(*)[256]` in this case) and you lose all information on the size of the first dimension.

Passing the array by reference avoids this, except that you now have to specify the full array type including all array dimensions; template argument deduction then makes this automatic:

```
template <size_t N>
void passit(char (&names)[N][256]) {
    printf("%d\n", N);
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way that I can solve this problem without changing the function declaration??

Comment: @user482594: No. When you try to pass an array by value, it actually decays to a pointer (`char(*)[256]` in this case) and you lose all information on the size of the first dimension. Passing by reference avoids this, except you have to specify the full array type; template argument deduction makes this automatic.